# scipy stats, finding the distribution giving an initial value

Tags: python, scipy

I have an initial value: X1 which has a minimum value of 5.

I want to find the normal distribution for the value X2 which has an expected mean of X1+3 with the "3" being a prediction that follows a standard error of 1.5. So the average value of X2 is 8.

Below is the formula I would normally use to find the probability distribution of X2, but this isn't correct in this case since there isnt'y any probability of it being below 5.

```
X1 = 5
estmean = 3
X2 = X1+estmean
mydist = stats.norm(X2,1.5)
dist = mydist.pdf(range(25))
```

A bandaid fix might be the following:

```
mydist = stats.norm(X2,1.5)
dist =  mydist.pdf(range(5,25))
```

However, that doesn't seem like a proper solution and would also be extremely impractical to imlement given how I set up the rest of the code.

I would be very thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `truncnorm` is what you are looking for?

```
rv = stats.truncnorm(-2, np.inf, scale=1.5, loc=X1+3)
```

`rv.pdf` looks like this

[image]